# args of short flag and long flag are parsed differently in commander module node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, flags, node-commander

```
program
  .command("split")
  .description("Split a string into substrings and display as an array")
  .argument("<string>", "string to split")
  .option("--first", "display just the first substring")
  .option("-s ,--separator <char>", "separator character", ",")
  .action((str, options) => {
  console.log(options);
  const limit = options.first ? 1 : undefined;
  console.log(str.split(options.separator, limit));
 });
```

-s="l" is parsed as {seperator:"=l"}

--seperator="l" is parsed as {seperator :"l"}

how to get uniform parsing either as "=l" or "l" while using both short and long flags

Comment: The behavior you're seeing is pretty much standard, especially for Node programs.

Comment: For interest, coverage of patterns used by widely used implementations and POSIX standard: github.com/pkgjs/parseargs/issues/78

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported forms for specifying an option and option-argument in Commander are

```
serve -p 80
serve --port 80
serve -p80
serve --port=80
```

There is not support in Commander for making the short and long options "uniform" for the combined option and value form.

The short form comes from [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_01) and [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html) guidelines.

#### POSIX [Utility Conventions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_01)

> If the SYNOPSIS of a standard utility shows an option with a mandatory option-argument (as with [ -c option_argument] in the example), a conforming application shall use separate arguments for that option and its option-argument. However, a conforming implementation shall also permit applications to specify the option and option-argument in the same argument string without intervening  characters.

#### GNU [Program Argument Syntax Conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html)

> An option and its argument may or may not appear as separate tokens. (In other words, the whitespace separating them is optional.) Thus, `-o foo` and `-ofoo` are equivalent.

(I am a maintainer of Commander.)